# How to active a code when it hasn't been born yet

Tags: jquery

i am having some problems here. Here is my code:

```
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                     $("#button").click(function(){
                         alert("hello");
                         var a = $("textarea").val();
                         var b = $("#search").val();
                         var c = $("textarea").length;
                         var d = $("#search").length;
                         var array = [];
                         var st = "";
                         for(var e=0;e<c;e++)
                         {
                            for (var f=0;f<d;f++)
                            {
                               if(a[e+f] === b[f])
                               {
                                    alert(a[e+f]);
                                    array.push(a[e+f]);
                                    if (array.length === d)
                                    {
                                    for(var g in array)
                                       {
                                        st += array[g];
                                       }
                                        a.substr(e,e+f).replaceWith("vinh");
                                        break;                                      
                                    }                                   
                               }
                               else
                               {
                               break;
                               }
                            }

                         }
                     });
                });
```

The bad news is that when the document is ready, there isn't any $("#button") at first. Only after i trigger a code that append button to html but it is too late, the button won't run. Can anyone solve this ?. Many thanks to your help

Comment: Instead of using just click, use $("#button").on('click', function(){ ..

Comment: Are you injecting button using jquery to the HTML DOM?

Comment: Search for event delegation.

Comment: is it the same addEventListener? - Samir

Comment: Check this [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Yes it is same, Please check my answer below and try.

Comment: To Tharsan Sivakumar (your name is really hard to write) i said it, i inject it  through a javascript code

Comment: It didn't work - Samir -

Comment: I have modified the answer, please check that once...

Comment: I believe that when the document is ready, it doesn't find button. And for that, the button won't run

Comment: The .on("click" function) can be used for the element which are loaded at run time. I think the answer will give you the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to trigger `click` on dynamically created element is to `listen` to the click `event` in DOM then fire it on your desire `element` then it will check for the target where is `click` been fired.

**Use**

```
$(document).on("click","#button",function(){ // code goes here })
```

> Learn more about `.on` visit the official jquery documentation **[Click Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click","#button" function(){
    alert("hello");
    var a = $("textarea").val(),
        b = $("#search").val(),
        c = $("textarea").length,
        d = $("#search").length,
        array = [],
        st = "";

    for(var e=0;e<c;e++){
        for (var f=0;f<d;f++){
            if(a[e+f] === b[f]){
                alert(a[e+f]);
                array.push(a[e+f]);
                if (array.length === d){
                    for(var g in array){
                    st += array[g];
                    }
                    a.substr(e,e+f).replaceWith("vinh");
                    break;                                      
                }                                   
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }                                       
});
});
```

Comment: it works but you forgot a comma between "#button" and function()

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the buttons parent for this. This is an example using "body" as parent:

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function(){
    // Add your code here
}
```

Take a look at this thread for more info: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the jQuery code to be run on the button element in a separate .js file and load it asynchronously after the code that loads this button using $.getScript().